# Write two variables to a file inside a for loop

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write two variable to a file inside a for loop using Python.
Here is a Minimum Working Example (MWE)

```
for kk in range(1,10):
    vr = kk+1
    vm = kk+2
    f = open('vr_vm.txt','w')
    f.write("%s %s\n" % (vr, vm))
    f.close()
```

My problem is each time the code is overwriting the previously written line. How can i get rid of this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you are *opening* and *closing* the file on each iteration. At the end of an iteration, the file will be closed. Then, on the next iteration, it will be opened again, this process will *clean* the file (its content is deleted). Then you write the variables values in the empty file.

Therefore the content file after the loop will only be the last written values.

**How can you solve it?** Just put the `open`  and `close` calls outside the loop:

```
f = open('vr_vm.txt.txt', 'w')

for kk in range(1, 10):
    vr = kk + 1
    vm = kk + 2
    f.write("%s %s\n" % (vr, vm))

f.close()
```

**Note:** It's recommended to use the `with open(...) as ...:` syntax to open a file. This will implicitly close the file.

```
with open('input.txt', 'w') as f:
    for kk in range(1, 10):
        vr = kk + 1
        vm = kk + 2
        f.write("%s %s\n" % (vr, vm))
```

Comment: I don't know who downvotes the most well written answer of this question... You deserve my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

'w' mean "an existing file with the same name will be erased"

you need to change it to 'a' that is for append mode

this should work

```
for kk in range(1,10):
    vr = kk+1
    vm = kk+2
    f = open('vr_vm.txt','a')
    f.write("%s %s\n" % (vr, vm))
    f.close()
```

for more information use this [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

although it is not the best solution. if you can move the file opening and closing outside the loop that should also work.

```
f = open('input.txt', 'w')// 'w' if you dont want to append your data
for kk in range(1, 10):
    vr = kk + 1
    vm = kk + 2
    f.write("%s %s\n" % (vr, vm))

f.close()
```

Comment: `b` is not append mode.

Comment: typo :)  'a' opens the file for appending

Answer (score 1):

It is not overwriting the previous line. Every time you open a file in write mode (`w`), the file is cleared out.

In effect, you are only seeing the last line written because your loop keeps opening the file in write mode (effectively deleting its contents).

At the last iteration, the loop ends so only the last line appears.

You can simplify your code by using the `with` statement, which will only open the file *once*, and automatically close it as well:

```
with open('vr_vm.txt', 'w') as f:
    for kk in range(1, 10):
        vr = kk+1
        vm = kk+2
        f.write('%s %s\n' % (vr, vm))
```